# Replace a block of text using a pattern of Regex (in java)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove a block of texts from a file using Regular Expressions. 
Now I have the content of the file in one `String` but the `Matcher` cannot find the pattern.
The example file is:

```
\begin{comment}
this block should be removed
i.e. it need to be replaced
\end{comment}
this block should remains.
\begin{comment}
this should be removed too.
\end{comment}
```

I need to find the blocks starting with `\begin{comment}` and ending with `\end{comment}`, and then remove them.
This is the minimal code that I used. The regex that I'm using is `\\begin\{.*?\\end\{comment\}` which should find and pattern starting with '\begin' until the first occurrence of '\end{comment}'. I worked in Notepad++.

However using this java code, it find the first '\begin' and last '\end' lines and remove every thing in between. I want to keep the line which are not *within* the blocks.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String output;
        String s =  "\\begin{comment}\n"+
        "this block should be removed\n"+
        "i.e. it need to be replaced\n"+
        "\\end{comment}\n"+
        "this block should remains.\n"+
        "\\begin{comment}\n"+
        "this should be removed too.\n"+
        "\\end{comment}";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\\begin\\{comment(?s).*\\\\end\\{comm.*?\\}").matcher(s);
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
            output = m.replaceAll("");
        }

        m = Pattern.compile("\\begin").matcher(s);
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
            output = m.replaceAll("");
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I used [this](http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/#!;t=I%20lost%20my%20wallet%0AI%20lost%20my%20sablefish%0AI%20lost%20my%20parrot%0AI%20lost%20my%3A%20trooper&r=I%20lost%20my%3A%3F%20%5Cw%2B&x=) online tool to find it. 
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\begin\{comment(?s).*\\end\{comm.*?\}").matcher(s);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix your code in 2 points:

1. The pattern should be consistent with your *Notepad++* equivalent, the **star** should be followed by `?` to be **lazy**:

   ```
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\\begin\\{comment}(?s).*?\\\\end\\{comment}").matcher(s);
   -------------------------------------------------------^
   ```

Note that this pattern works correctly only if no nested comment section exists.

2. The latter fix regards the logic: if you call the matcher **replaceAll** function it replaces **every** matching section when executed (already at the first `m.find()` loop execution). If you need the loop to inspect every comment block replace it with:

   ```
   output = m.replaceFirst("");
   ```

   or simply apply `output = m.replaceAll("");` without any loop at all.